# Clarification about hyperspaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a separable metric space.

Let $2^X$ denote the set of closed subsets of $X$.

Question 1: Is the Hausdorff metric topology the same as the Vietoris topology in this case?

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/791334/hausdorff-metric-and-vietoris-topology) it is shown that if $X$ is compact then the answer is yes.  So, what if we let $Y$ be a metric compactification of $X$.  The two topologies are the same on $2^Y$, and so they induce the same subspace topology on $C(X)$, the set of compact subsets of $X$.  But of course $2^X$ is not even a subset of $2^Y$ in general.

If they are different, which one is preferable/most commonly used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use $H(X)$ for the hyperspace of non-empty (!) closed sets. $2^X$ is also common, but can also mean a function space/product, so this might be confusing.
The usual topology for $H(X)$ (and its subspaces) is the Vietoris topology.

$C(X)$ or $\mathcal{K}(X)$ denotes all compact non-empty subsets of $X$.

For Hausdorff spaces $C(X)$ is a subspace of $H(X)$. For compact Hausdorff spaces they're of course equal.

If $(X,d)$ is metrisable, the Hausdorff metric $d_H$ is well-defined on $C(X)$ by boundedness and it is well-known that the Vietoris topology on $C(X)$ and the $d_H$-topology coincide (see your own link).

For all topological spaces $X$, $H(X)$ metrisable implies that $X$ is compact and metrisable, and then $C(X) = H(X)$ and the previous applies. So $d_H$ (even if yould define it for all closed sets) cannot be a metric for the Vietoris topology on $H(X)$ for non-compact metric spaces.